# Prevent author role from editing others posts

Tags: custom-post-types, capabilities, user-roles

I have created a custom post type "Extension" and a role "Extension Author".
A user in this role should only be able to edit his/her own extensions.

As it is now the user can click "edit extension" in top bar and enter edit mode.

[image: Edit Extension Link]

How do i prevent an Extension Author from entering edit view of extensions not his/her own? Have I missed something when setting capabilities?

Creating custom post type:

```
$labels = array(
    'name'                => _x( 'Extensions', 'Post Type General Name', 'text_domain' ),
    'singular_name'       => _x( 'Extension', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
    'menu_name'           => __( 'Extensions', 'text_domain' ),
    'parent_item_colon'   => __( 'Parent Extension:', 'text_domain' ),
    'all_items'           => __( 'All Extensions', 'text_domain' ),
    'view_item'           => __( 'View Extension', 'text_domain' ),
    'add_new_item'        => __( 'Add New Extension', 'text_domain' ),
    'add_new'             => __( 'Add New', 'text_domain' ),
    'edit_item'           => __( 'Edit Extension', 'text_domain' ),
    'update_item'         => __( 'Update Extension', 'text_domain' ),
    'search_items'        => __( 'Search Extension', 'text_domain' ),
    'not_found'           => __( 'No Extensions found', 'text_domain' ),
    'not_found_in_trash'  => __( 'No Extensions found in Trash', 'text_domain' ),
);
$rewrite = array(
    'slug'                => 'extension',
    'with_front'          => true,
    'pages'               => true,
    'feeds'               => true,
);
$capabilities = array(
    'edit_post'           => 'edit_extension',
    'read_post'           => 'read_extension',
    'delete_post'         => 'delete_extension',
    'edit_posts'          => 'edit_extensions',
    'edit_others_posts'   => 'edit_others_extensions',
    'publish_posts'       => 'publish_extensions',
    'read_private_posts'  => 'read_private_extensions',
);
$args = array(
    'labels'              => $labels,
    'supports'            => array( 'title',),
    'hierarchical'        => false,
    'public'              => true,
    'show_ui'             => true,
    'show_in_menu'        => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
    'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
    'menu_position'       => 5,
    'menu_icon'           => 'dashicons-admin-generic',
    'can_export'          => true,
    'has_archive'         => true,
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
    'publicly_queryable'  => true,
    'rewrite'             => $rewrite,
    'capability_type'     => 'extension',
    'capabilities' => $capabilities,
);

register_post_type( 'extension', $args );
```

Creating user role:

```
    $extension_author_role = add_role('extension_author', 'Extension Author', array(
    'read' => true,
    'upload_files' => true,
    'edit_extension'   => true,
    'read_extension'   => true,
    'delete_extension'   => true,
    'edit_extensions'   => true,
    'edit_others_extensions'   => false,
    'publish_extensions'   => true,
    'read_private_extensions'   => false,
    )
);
```

Comment: You can have a good basic understandings from [this slide](http://www.slideshare.net/MayeenulIslam/wordpress-adding-userrole), I hope.

Answer (score 0):

Using this code snippet makes it that an author will see now only his/her
own posting 
and is only able to edit his/her own postings. Only Admins will now be able to edit all posting.

You could try to replace *'author'* with *'extension_author'* and see if it works 
for you as wished.
(Add snippet in functions.php or your own plugin)

```
function to_parse_query_useronly( $wp_query ) {
    if ( strpos( $_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_URI' ], '/wp-admin/edit.php' ) !== false ) {
        if ( !current_user_can( 'publish_posts' ) ) {
            global $current_user;
            $wp_query->set( 'author', $current_user->id );
        }
    }
}
add_filter('parse_query', 'to_parse_query_useronly' );
```